# React: Set focus on previous input after unmount

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of components which are rendered as `<input>` using the map function.

I know that I can focus on the last rendered element by using `autofocus` or `this.refs.input.focus`

What if I want to focus on the previous input, **after one of them has unmounted**? Is there a way to make use of the component key in parent to focus on the child component rendered with the previous key?

### parent.js:

```
renderData() {
    return theData.map((d) => {
      return (
        <Child
          key = {d}
        />
      )
    })
}

render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.renderData()}
      </div>
    )
}
```

### child.js:

```
componentWillUnmount(){
    //probably do stuff here
}

render() {
    return(
      <input
        autoFocus
        ref="input"
      />
    )
  }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: yes you can refer child components in parent, just add `ref` to every child

Comment: You can try to find child's tab index and onWillUnmount set tabIndex -= 1.

Comment: how does the component unmount ? who performs that ?

Comment: Hi @Dhiraj, thank you for your reply. I have a separate component for the user to delete data (by calling a meteor method), where this input component will then unmount

Comment: there can probably be a logic in parent that determines which child to focus. During delete data, if the parent's state changes, re-rendering happens and the logic to determine is evaluated and based on that appropriate child can have focus. Hope this makes sense

Comment: @Dhiraj I thought of that, and can figure out the childID to focus in the parent component. What will be the correct way to call focus() on the child? I need something like `this.child[key=id].refs.input.focus()` which I can't seem to figure out

Comment: If wouldn't do that. I would rather send props to childen to focus
`<Child focus={child1Focus}><Child focus={child2Focus}>`
The parent should determine which focus value should be True and which one should be False. This way inside the child Component, depending on the props it received, either focus it or not

Comment: @Dhiraj thank you for the suggestion. I thought there may have been an easier way, and didn't even think about passing props. I'll go ahead with that!